# Attempt to dismiss from view controller <UINavigationController: 0x717f0f0> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress

Tags: iphone, ios

I am an iOS rookie. I have a Table View embedded in a Navigation Controller. Another Table View is also embedded in a Navigation Controller. The first Table View, ChecklistsView, presents the second Table View, ItemDetailView. The ChecklistView's Navigation Controller '+' button opens the ItemDetailView scene. Tapping on the Cancel button of the ItemDetailView closes the ItemDetailView, but gives the message noted above. Here is the code for the Cancel method:

```
- (IBAction)cancel
{
    [self.delegate itemDetailViewControllerDidCancel:self];
}
```

And here is the delegate method used in the cancel method:

```
- (void)itemDetailViewControllerDidCancel:(ItemDetailViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I have reviewed other posts about this warning, but they are above my level of expertise.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have the delegate dismiss the viewController.

Rather you should dismiss it by using the .presentingViewController property on the presentedViewController.

Like so:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with AdamG. What you're doing is correct; Apple also uses this design, where the delegate dismisses the controller (check out [MFMessageComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MFMessageComposeViewController/messageComposeDelegate)).

Back to the question, if I understand you correctly, and that you have the following structure (pardon the terms, but you'll get the gist):

- A `UINavigationController` at the top
- `ChecklistsViewController` is the navigation controller's root view controller
- `ItemDetailViewController` as a modal view controller
- `ChecklistsViewController` is the delegate for `ItemDetailViewController`

It's just the implementation details in your case.

```
- (void) itemDetailViewControllerDidCancel: (ItemDetailViewController*) controller
{
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES
                                   completion: nil];
}
```

Comment: Using the code recommended by Vrol, I continue to get the same message (warning).

Comment: @JimBotts: This warning appears if you dismiss the same view controller twice. Check if your dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: calls are being called one after the other, maybe from different classes. Make sure that only the delegate dismisses the view controller, nothing else.

Comment: I commented out two other lines calling dismissViewController as you recommended and I still get the message. Thanks.